# Django can't save form data

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working on a django project and faced a weird problem.
I am using `model form` for this.
Even though I wrote `form.save()` as you can see it below, new data is not saved.

```
# in views.py
class ProductUpdateView(self, request, product_id):
def get(self, request, product_id):
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        name = product.name
        id = product.id
        form = ProductEditForm(instance=product)
        context = {
            "form": form,
            "name": name,
            "id": id,
        }
        return render(request, "management/product_detail.html", context)
    

    def post(self, request, product_id):
        form = ProductEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f"'{product.name}' is successfully updated!")
            return redirect("products_list")
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "form is invalid")
            return redirect("products_list")
```

```
# in forms.py
class ProductEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["name", "description", "price", "is_available", "category"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs["class"] = "form-control"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir can you try this and give me the feedback of it i am not sure about this
this just to change the name of the product other function may not work

```
form = ProductEditForm(request.POST )
product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
if form.is_valid():
    product.name = request.POST['name']
    product.save()
    messages.success(request, f"'{product.name}' is successfully updated!")
    return redirect("products_list")
```

instance=request.user sir i removed it you and add it back i don't know the use of it

welcome sir

Comment: Thank you @jashandeep singh. I will try this.

Comment: Your welcome sir once again sir i am also working the django website. i want to  contact you my insta id is jashandeep_ghatrora if you don't want to contact then atleast reply with no

Comment: Sorry @jashandeep singh, I am not interested in social media.

Comment: no problem we will help each other on the stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem!

```
# views.py
def post(self, request, product_id):
        form = ProductEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            # get category instance
            category = Category.objects.get(id=int(request.POST["category"]))
            # is_available
            if request.POST["is_available"] == "on":
                is_available = True
            else:
                is_available = False

            product.name = request.POST["name"]
            product.description = request.POST["description"]
            product.price = request.POST["price"]
            product.is_available = is_available
            product.category = category
            product.save()

            messages.success(request, f"'{product.name}' is successfully updated!")
            return redirect("products_list")
        else:
            messages.warning(request, "form is invalid")
            return redirect("products_list")
```